# If A is a subset of X, then the union of A and A complent equals X

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone look at my proof and offer corrections or tips? Thanks.

Problem:

If A $\subset$ X, then A $\cup$ $A^c$= X

My solution:

Let A $\subset$ X and let n$\in$ A $\cup$ $A^c$. Then n $\in$ A or n $\in$ $A^c$. If n $\in$ A, then because A $\subset$ X we have that n $\in$ X. If  n$\in$ $A^c$, Then by definition n $\in$ X. Thus $A \cup A^c \subset X.$

Now let n $\in$ X. Then there are only two possibilities. Either n $\in$ A or n $\in$ $A^c$. Thus n $\in$ $ A \cup A^c$ So X $\subset$ A $\cup$ $A^c$

Comment: If you are proving at this level of detail, I would amend the proof of $X \subset A \cup A^c$ in one place: "There are two possibilities: $n \in A$ or $n \not\in A$. Since $A^c$ is defined as those elements in $X$ that $\not\in A$, $n \in A^c$." Otherwise I think the proof is complete and correct.